# Building an SMS server for receiving SMS

Tags: mysql, windows, webserver, modem

I am working on a project where I am building a server that can receive SMS from any mobile phone via a longcode (Phone Number) given to the user to send the SMS

This SMS is received by my server via a Modem with a SIM card inside the modem and can be used to process other kinds of operations

For example for updating Facebook status, for posting Tweets, obtaining Latest New Information and much more

Now i started this project in 2011 but the challenge I hard was that, i used a .NET dll library from logixmobile.com called mCore Library. I could receive only a single SMS at a time and process them but could not receive more.

Please how can i build this kind of server. Also would it be ok for me to use Windows for the system or linux

Also if a code can be written for me to handle as many SMS as possible i would be glad to have it.

Comment: How could you receive sms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work for [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com), which allows you to add Voice and SMS into you applications using the cloud. So instead of an SMS modem (I've had 'fun' with those myself!) you set use a web server. You can buy a telephone number from Twilio in over 40 countries, and simply configure that number to send the SMS messages to your server - [a simple .Net web application is a great way to go](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/01/twilio-for-net-developers-part-2-adding-twilio-helper-libraries-to-your-project.html). You can host it yourself, or use [Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/twilio-voice-and-sms-service/).

There is a nice tutorial on [how to get started here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/hello-monkey).

Comment: But can i get a Twilio SIM card in my country? Which countries can i get it?